# ObjectMapper.readvalue in json

Tags: java, json, junit

In object mapper class am getting **JsonParseException** when i pass parameter as "abc,asd"(for Junit test purpose) . Please clarify why am getting this exception.
What value it will accept it for further processing.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<LinkedHashMap> listM=mapper .readValue("abc,asd",ArrayList.class);
for (Iterator iterator = listM.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                LinkedHashMap linkedMap = (LinkedHashMap) iterator.next();
syso("linkedMap .get(methodname).get(0)")
```

Comment: `What value it will accept` valid JSON values, for starters... http://json.org/ for the format and http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this exception because `abc,asd` is not a valid JSON. JSON is a Javascript Object that basically has key and value. Example:

`{"abc":"abc"}`

And can get a List of these:

`[{"abc":"abc"}, {"asd":"asd"}]`

So, a valid code would be:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<LinkedHashMap> listM = mapper.readValue("[{\"abc\":\"abc\"}, {\"asd\":\"asd\"}]", ArrayList.class);
    for (Iterator iterator = listM.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        LinkedHashMap linkedMap = (LinkedHashMap) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(linkedMap);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine now. But i need to get list of output. Example: System.out.println(((ArrayList<String>) linkedMap.get("abc")).get(0)); for all key i need to get list of values. for that wat kind of JSON format input ineed to give it to mapper.readvalue

Comment: If I get this well, you can do: `mapper.readValue("[{\"values\":[\"abc\", \"asd\"]}]", ArrayList.class);` and use: `System.out.println((ArrayList<String>) linkedMap.get("values"));`